# Rails, Has and belongs to many, match all conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models Article and Category

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord

  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

end
```

I want to get Articles that have category 1 AND category 2 associated.

```
Article.joins(:categories).where(categories: {id: [1,2]}  )
```

The code above won't do it because if an Article with category 1 OR category 2 is associated then it will be returned and thats not the goal. Both must match.

Comment: I faced exact same problem. Solution should be `Article.joins(:categories).where(categories: { id: 1 }).where(categories: { id: 2 })` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is to join the same table multiple times. Here is an untested class method on Article:

```
def self.must_have_categories(category_ids)
  scope = self

  category_ids.each do |category_id|
    scope = scope.joins("INNER JOIN articles_categories as ac#{category_id} ON articles.id = ac#{category_id}.article_id").
        where("ac#{category_id}.category_id = ?", category_id)
  end

  scope
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query only those articles of the first category, which are also the articles of the second category.

It's going to be something like this:

```
Article.joins(:categories)
  .where(categories: { id: 1 })
  .where(id: Article.joins(:categories).where(categories: { id: 2 }))
```

Note, that it can be:

```
Category.find(1).articles.where(id: Category.find(2).articles)
```

but it makes additional requests and requires additional attention to the cases when category can't be found.